# PayPal SDK REST API state "approved" vs "completed" vs "verified"?

Tags: php, paypal-rest-sdk

While using PayPal SDK REST Api, **How to confirm that payment has "completed" as in *completed-completed*?**

Right now the API is returning multiple attributes which is a bit confusing on what attribute to depend upon to proceed with the checkout process.

There is this `state` field in the root attributes of the response object.

```
state -> approved
```

Then there is this `payer` field which has a `status` of its own, and its showing ...

```
status -> VERIFIED
```

Then there is this `sale` object inside the `transactions` object and it also has a `state` which is showing..

`state-> completed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per the [Docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/paypal-payments/#next)

> A sale is a completed payment.

Which implies that we need to check for the `sale -> state` flag.

```
$transactions = $payment->getTransactions();
$related_resources = $transactions[0]->getRelatedResources();
$sale = $related_resources[0]->getSale();
$sale_state = $sale->getState(); // 'complete' Or 'pending' or etc..
```